# Работа с таблицами из БД

Tags: база-данных, visual-studio, c#

Здравствуйте!

1) Как получить число таблиц в БД? Их имена? И как с ними работать в общем случае?

К примеру, я хочу при запуске приложения получить список таблиц в БД, а затем щелчком на одном из значений, открывать таблицу.

На данном этапе, я работаю так:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=Склад.mdb");
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Товары";
            OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            dataAdapter.SelectCommand = command;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
            connection.Close();
        }
```

Понятно, что я вывожу одну таблицу Товары.

Как к примеру обратиться к той или иной таблице? Получить имена её столбцов, их тип и т.д?... Особенно это необходимо при создании формы для записи данных...

2) Кое-что получилось. Через обозреватель серверов я создал подключение к моей базе данных, и получился объект типа DataSet. Далее поработав с ним я добился следующего:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Sklad mySklad = new Sklad();
            //MessageBox.Show("Число таблиц в БД "+mySklad.Tables.Count.ToString());
            foreach (DataTable dt in mySklad.Tables)
            {
                DataGridView dtGrid = new DataGridView();
                tabControl1.TabPages.Add(dt.TableName);
                dtGrid.Parent = tabControl1.TabPages[tabControl1.TabPages.Count-1];
                dtGrid.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                dtGrid.Name = "Table_" + dt.TableName;
                dtGrid.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
                dtGrid.Show();

            }
        }
```

Но, таблицы выводятся пустые. Куда делись данные? Или как их вывести? Я понимаю что надо через запрос, но как взаимодействовать через запрос с этим объектом DataSet...

Спасибо!

Comment: если я не ошибаюсь, то ваши таблицы в DataSet можно перетащить прямиком на форму.

Comment: И что это даст? ПОдскажите, как дальше работать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С MS Access можно работать так:

```
OleDbConnection cnn;

// ...

var tables = cnn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
```

Можно передавать туда другие значения OleDbSchemaGuid

Answer (score 0):

Вам помогут вот эти команды:

- **SHOW DATABASES;**
- **SHOW TABLES FROM** *`имя_базы_данных`***;**
- **SHOW COLUMNS FROM** *`имя_базы_данных`***.***`имя_таблицы`***;**

Comment: Неа, не помогут... Я пробовал) VS ругается на то, что допускаются только команды SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, и еще чего то...

Comment: Это для какой СУБД такие команды?

Comment: BogolyubskiyAlexey привел команды для MySQL, а я с Access работаю..

Comment: Я вот и смотрю, что ни MS Access, ни MS Sql Server такое не поддерживают.